# Retrieve the Data From the RealmDatabase and Set it to GridView

Tags: android, json, gridview, realm

I am able to Save the JSON Data to the Realm Database. I have used as the documentation of the Realm, but I am not able to set the data to the GridView. I am using Custom Adapter not the Realm Adapter. The Data are Logged but they are not Displayed to the GridView. How can this the Data be Retrieved and Displayed to the GridView?

**PopularDestinationGridDetail**  this is where JSON data is parsed and saved to database

```
 Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  LinearAddTOFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                savetoDatabase();
            }
        });


    public void savetoDatabase() {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                RealmDatabasePopularDestination realmDatabasePopularDestination = bgRealm.createObject(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class);
                realmDatabasePopularDestination.setTitle(title);
                realmDatabasePopularDestination.setTitle(latitude);
                realmDatabasePopularDestination.setTitle(longitude);
                realmDatabasePopularDestination.setImage(image);

//                Toast.makeText(this,  realmDatabasePopularDestination.setLatitude(realmDatabasePopularDestination1.getLatitude()))


            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                Log.v("Success",title);


            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("failed", error.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }
```

**Favourites**

```
public class Favourites extends Fragment {

    Realm realm;
    GridView gridViewBookmark;
    ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> destination_bookmark_realm = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Realm.init(getContext());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


        RealmDatabasePopularDestination realmDatabasePopularDestination = new RealmDatabasePopularDestination();


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_layout_gridview, container, false);
        gridViewBookmark = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewBookmark);
        destination_bookmark_realm.add(realmDatabasePopularDestination);
        getData();
        return view;

    }


    public void getData() {
        FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getContext(), destination_bookmark_realm);
        gridViewBookmark.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);

        RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> result = realm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).equalTo("Title","niyash temple").findAll();

        result.load();

        System.out.println("Result is" + result);

//        String output = "";
//        for (RealmDatabasePopularDestination realmDatabasePopularDestination : result) {
//
//
//            output += realmDatabasePopularDestination.toString();
//
//        }
//
//        System.out.println("output" + output);
//        System.out.println("Total size=" + result.size());

    }

}
```

**getter and setter**

```
public class RealmDatabasePopularDestination extends RealmObject {

    String Title;
    String Latitude;
    String Longitude;
    String image;



    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**FavouriteAdapter**

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public FavouriteAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.clas_realm_bookmark = clas_realm_bookmark;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return clas_realm_bookmark.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return clas_realm_bookmark.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final FavouriteAdapter.Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_grid_list_item, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder = new FavouriteAdapter.Holder();

            // viewHolder.popular_destintion_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.festivalName);
            viewHolder.imageLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_festival_main_image);


            //     Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + position + " getTeacherName" + class_destination.get(position).getId());
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            //  viewHolder = (ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.title.setText(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getTitle());


        Picasso.with(mContext).load(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getImage()).error(R.drawable.close).into(viewHolder.imageLogo);


        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView imageLogo;

    }


}
```

I am not getting any error but they are not set on the ListView.This is the first time using realm, so don't get where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting adapter to list view before extracting data from database.

```
RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> result = realm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).equalTo("Title","niyash temple").findAll();
result.load();

FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getContext(), destination_bookmark_realm);
gridViewBookmark.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);
```

use above code and.

destination_bookmark_realm it should be load with the result you got from databse

Comment: getting output like this
I/System.out: Result is[RealmDatabasePopularDestination = proxy[{Title:85.3404},{Latitude:null},{Longitude:null},{image:http://192.168.100.7:1337/images/popular_places/Patan-2.jpg}]]
08-14 16:05:48.704 16347-16347/org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null;
```

You should be using `RealmBaseAdapter` from [realm-android-adapters](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) as specified in the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters).

Comment: Do RealmBaseAdapter  is compulsory or we can use any of custom Adapter???

Comment: well you can use any adapter as long as you use `RealmResults<T>` instead of `ArrayList` and you also properly manage `RealmChangeListener` calling the right `adapter.notify*` methods when the data set changes. If you don't want to manually manage `RealmChangeListener` then use `RealmBaseAdapter`.

Comment: Thank you,This also helps me. , i have solved with Custom adapter anyway.

Comment: Now I wonder what happens if you delete one of the objects from the Realm and then you click the row...

Comment: I have not checked that now.What will happen, suggest .Have you done this sorts of problem before.Can't there be problem if i replace the custom Adapter with the Adapter provide with realm,with same code?

Comment: well you can always [check the source code of RealmBaseAdapter and see if you're missing anything](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/34bad2f1ef98daa3b13efa5fb5851678d88e2f3f/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java#L43-L152).

Comment: i will surely apply your advice tomorrow on my project :). All the JSON data are saved in the database and retrieved in the bookmark page.As the bookmark grid item is clicked it would intent to its Detail page. I got confused that i have already grid Detail page which parse JSON directly and Display it .How can this be matched ,to the page intent from Bookmark,this will be locally stored as it came from bookmark page..Logic needed

Comment: If the data is available, then obtain it from Realm as RealmResults. If it is not available, then download it from remote, the RealmChangeListener will update things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151896/discussion-between-ghimire-and-epicpandaforce).