# Super Method in BaseAdapter cannot be initialised in RealmBaseAdapter

Tags: android, realm, adapter, delete-row

I am using Realm Database to Save the Data From the JSON  within the Mobile.I am using Custom Adapter rather than the RealmAdapter.I am able to save the Data and Retrieve the Data from the Realm Database but when i delete the item by position i got an error, that says the Object is no longer valid to operate on.

**ToDoRealmAdapter**

```
 public class ToDoRealmAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> {
    Context mContext;
    RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public ToDoRealmAdapter(@NonNull Context context, RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark) {
        super(context, clas_realm_bookmark);

        this.context = mContext;
        this.clas_realm_bookmark = clas_realm_bookmark;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_grid_list_item, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder = new Holder();


            // viewHolder.popular_destintion_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.festivalName);
            viewHolder.imageLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_festival_main_image);
            viewHolder.location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventAddress);
            viewHolder.monthEvent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDateBookmark);


            viewHolder.textViewIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageLocationBookmark);
            //     Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + position + " getTeacherName" + class_destination.get(position).getId());
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            //  viewHolder = (ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.title.setText(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.location.setText(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getLocation());

        if (clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getType().equals("popular_destination")) {
            viewHolder.monthEvent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewHolder.textViewIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fav_icon_popular);

        } else {
            viewHolder.monthEvent.setText(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getDateEvent());
            viewHolder.textViewIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.events_festival_icon);
        }
        System.out.println("Display" + clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getDateEvent());
        Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(mContext);


//        picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        picasso.load(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getImage()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).error(R.drawable.close).into(viewHolder.imageLogo, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                //Try again online if cache failed
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getImage())
                        .error(R.drawable.close)
                        .into(viewHolder.imageLogo, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                Log.v("Picasso", "Could not fetch image");
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        //Picasso.with(mContext).load(clas_realm_bookmark.get(position).getImage()).error(R.drawable.close).into(viewHolder.imageLogo);


        return convertView;
    }




    class Holder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView imageLogo;
        TextView location;
        TextView monthEvent;
        ImageView textViewIcon;


    }
}
```

**PopularDestinationGridDetail**

```
 public void savetoDatabase() {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                //
                count = (int) bgRealm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).equalTo("Id", id).equalTo("Type", type).count();//mofidy Query here
                if (count > 0) {

                } else {
                    RealmDatabasePopularDestination realmDatabasePopularDestination = bgRealm.createObject(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setId(id);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setTitle(title);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setLatitude(latitude);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setLongitude(longitude);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setImage(image);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setType(type);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setLocation(location);
                    realmDatabasePopularDestination.setDescription(description);
                    Log.v("Success", realmDatabasePopularDestination.getTitle());

                }


            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (count > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(PopularDestinationGridDetail.this, "Already added", LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PopularDestinationGridDetail.this, "Added to Favorites", LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                Log.v("Success", title);

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("failed", error.getMessage());
            }
        });


    }
```

**Favourites**

```
public class Favourites extends Fragment {

    Realm realm;
    GridView gridViewBookmark;
    RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> destination_bookmark_realm =null;
    RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> realmDatabasePopularDestinations;

    FavouriteAdapter favouriteAdapter;

    ToDoRealmAdapter toDoRealmAdapter;
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination>> realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> databasePopularDestinations) {

            toDoRealmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Realm.init(getContext());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark_layout_gridview, container, false);
        gridViewBookmark = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridviewBookmark);
        getData();
        getGridItemClick();
        return view;

    }
    RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> result;

    public void getData() {
       result = realm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).findAll();
        result.load();

//        System.out.println("Result" + result.get(0).getTitle());

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

            //if(result.get(i).getType().equals("popular_destination")) {

            destination_bookmark_realm.add(result.get(i));
            //}else{
            //  destination_bookmark_realm.add(result.get(i));
            //}

        }


//        favouriteAdapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getContext(), destination_bookmark_realm);
//        gridViewBookmark.setAdapter(favouriteAdapter);


        toDoRealmAdapter = new ToDoRealmAdapter(getContext(),  destination_bookmark_realm);
        gridViewBookmark.setAdapter(toDoRealmAdapter);
        destination_bookmark_realm.addChangeListener((RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination>>) realmChangeListener);


        System.out.println("Result is" + result);


    }

    String type;

    public void getType(final int pos) {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                //
                RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> results = bgRealm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).findAll();//mofidy Query here

                type = results.get(pos).getType();
                System.out.println("LOg2" + type);

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("failed", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }


    public void getGridItemClick() {

        gridViewBookmark.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                getType(position);
                System.out.println("LOg" + type);
                if (type == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (type.equals("popular_destination")) {


                    System.out.println("LOg4" + type);
                    Intent Bookmark_Popular_Des_grid_intent = new Intent(getContext(), PopularDestinationGridDetail.class);
                    Bundle popular_destination_bundle = new Bundle();
                    popular_destination_bundle.putString("Popular_Destination_ID", String.valueOf(destination_bookmark_realm.get(position).getId()));
                    popular_destination_bundle.putString("Fav_Flag", "1");
                    Bookmark_Popular_Des_grid_intent.putExtras(popular_destination_bundle);
                    startActivity(Bookmark_Popular_Des_grid_intent);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("LOg5" + type);

                    Intent Bookmark_Event_fes_grid_intent = new Intent(getContext(), EventAndFestivalGridDetail.class);
                    Bundle event_festival_bundle = new Bundle();
                    event_festival_bundle.putString("Event_Festival_ID", String.valueOf(destination_bookmark_realm.get(position).getId()));
                    event_festival_bundle.putString("Fav_Flag", "2");
                    Bookmark_Event_fes_grid_intent.putExtras(event_festival_bundle);
                    startActivity(Bookmark_Event_fes_grid_intent);
                }


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        result.removeAllChangeListeners();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

**log**

```
e: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage, PID: 31896
                                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field handlerController of type Lio/realm/HandlerController; in class Lio/realm/BaseRealm; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.realm.BaseRealm' appears in /data/app/org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage-2/base.apk)
                                                                                           at io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter.addListener(RealmBaseAdapter.java:67)
                                                                                           at io.realm.RealmBaseAdapter.<init>(RealmBaseAdapter.java:60)
                                                                                           at org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage.adapter.ToDoRealmAdapter.<init>(ToDoRealmAdapter.java:36)
                                                                                           at org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage.activity.PopularDestinationGridDetail.onCreate(PopularDestinationGridDetail.java:121)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

> How can this issue be solved??

Comment: You need to refresh your adapter in the `onSucess` call from the async transactions when you delete objects from Realm, otherwise, you risk it accessing a deleted item which will give you the error you see. The Realm adapters do this automatically for you.

Comment: How can I refrsh  on the onSuccess method

Comment: `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: Same error .Code edited

Comment: Actually I'd probably just tell him to use a RealmChangeListener as he normally would if he were using `RealmBaseAdapter`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you hve told me that ,this error arise.Can't i remove this error by using the Custom Adapter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673470/2413303 just like I said in the comments, if you provide `List` instead of ArrayList and that is the RealmResults and you manage the change listener outside of the adapter to notify when data set changes then it should work, as long as you remove the external change listener in `onDestroy`

Comment: Creating a new adapter will definitely not work, you need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the original adapter, but like @EpicPandaForce said, using a `RealmChangeListener` on the `RealmResults` will probably be easier. See https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java#L60

Comment: @christianMelchior can you plese help me to create the Adapter extending the RealmBase

Comment: You are creating the adapter and the changelistener inside the async transaction. That code is running on another thread and will not work.

Comment: what do i have to do.Do i have to run it out of thread.Can you give some hint

Comment: I got error of   Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Comment: The code for `PopularDestinationGridDetail` is missing.

Comment: can i paste my whole code

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you help me to work with the realmAdapter.I am bit Confused in realmAdapter

Comment: I've already answered this question :(

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i have changed as you said but have error.Updated with recent Adapter as well as Code

Comment: Please update the question

Comment: I have updated Title, with Recent Code

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a given RealmObject on any thread, then when Realm becomes updated (and RealmChangeListeners are called), then that object will no longer be valid, and will no longer be available in any `RealmResults<T>` that previously had it.

However you for whatever reason copy the contents of the RealmResults to an ArrayList

```
ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.addAll(realmResults); // <-- DON'T DO THIS AT HOME
```

which is super-duper horrible, because not only will the result set no longer update, but it will also be able to store and retain invalid objects.

Therefore,

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null; // <-- BAD

    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public FavouriteAdapter(Context mContext, 
      ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark) { // <-- BAD
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
```

and should be either

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null;

    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public FavouriteAdapter(Context mContext, List<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
```

with

```
RealmResults<...> results;
FavouriteAdapter adapter;
RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<...>> realmChangeListener = (element) -> {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
};

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
   ....
   results = realm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).findAll();
   FavouriteAdapter adapter = new FavouriteAdapter(this, results);
   results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    ....
   results.removeAllChangeListeners();
   realm.close();
}
```

---

OR

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> {

    Context mContext;
    //ArrayList<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> clas_realm_bookmark = null;

    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public FavouriteAdapter(Context mContext, RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> results) {
        super(results);
       ...
```

---

EDIT: also, remove the commented code entirely

```
     ...executeTransactionAsync(realm -> {
            if (count > 0) {
   //             RealmResults<RealmDatabasePopularDestination> result = bgRealm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).equalTo("Id", pop_dest_id).equalTo("Type", "popular_destination").findAll();
  //              result.deleteAllFromRealm();

      //          results = realm.where(RealmDatabasePopularDestination.class).equalTo("Id", pop_dest_id).equalTo("Type", "popular_destination").findAll();
   //             adapter = new FavouriteAdapter(getApplicationContext(), results);
   //             results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

Comment: what does element means here
RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<...>> realmChangeListener = (element) -> {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
};

Comment: error log says E/failed: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Comment: ..well I didn't even realize that you are trying to create a new adapter inside the asynchronous tranasaction block. There are about 3 things wrong with that, so just remove the code for it.

Comment: Which one that i have to remove from the code.I am having error like this
 Unable to destroy activity {org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage/org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage.activity.PopularDestinationGridDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.RealmResults.addChangeListener(io.realm.RealmChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: ....if you get NPE for *that* then you didn't copy the code I provided correctly.

Comment: you'll need to update your question with the new code, then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152226/discussion-between-ghimire-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: You need to move the adapter initialization to `onCreate()` as I said.